# How to Update database using linq and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit(DepositTicket dt)
    {
        using (var db = new MatchGamingEntities())
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
            Guid UserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
            var MyAccount = from a in db.Accounts
                            where a.UserId == UserId
                            select new Account{ 
                                AccountId = a.AccountId,                                 
                                Balance = a.Balance
                                };

            BankTransaction transaction = new BankTransaction();
            transaction.Amount = dt.Amount;
            transaction.AccountId = MyAccount.SingleOrDefault().AccountId;
            transaction.Created = DateTime.Today;
            transaction.TransactionType = "Credit";
            Debug.Write("Amount: " + transaction.Amount + " AccountId " + transaction.AccountId);
            db.BankTransactions.AddObject(transaction);
            MyAccount.SingleOrDefault().Balance += transaction.Amount;
            //Update Query

            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

Where the comment "Update Query" is, is where I want to add an update query to updated the Account table with an Account object.  I want to update the exisiting record, can this be done using the predefined functions for db.Accounts or would I have to write a linq query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are going to an awful lot of trouble to get a custom account object to then just want to update the original account record.  I would suggest just working with the original account object and make the necessary updates, then when SaveChanges is called it will update your account record.

Here are my suggested changes

```
public ActionResult Deposit(DepositTicket dt)
{
    using (var db = new MatchGamingEntities())
    {
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid UserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        var MyAccount = db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(a => a.UserId == UserId);

        BankTransaction transaction = new BankTransaction();
        transaction.Amount = dt.Amount;
        transaction.AccountId = MyAccount.AccountId;
        transaction.Created = DateTime.Today;
        transaction.TransactionType = "Credit";
        Debug.Write(String.Format("Amount: {0} AccountId: {1}", transaction.Amount, transaction.AccountId);
        db.BankTransactions.AddObject(transaction);
        MyAccount.Balance += transaction.Amount;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`db.SaveChanges();` will do the update for you, unless you have predefined SP in db.